# Unable to connect via wifi in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wireless, networking

So, as the title suggests, I am unable to connect to any wifi network. LAN works just fine and the PC sees all of the networks near me (though, the ones I've connected to show almost 0% signal strength). I've been trying different things to no avail such as rebooting, disabling and re-enabling the wireless card (Realtek RTL8188EE), among other things that I've found online. I've run out of options and really don't want to reinstall, so some help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to system settings.
2.Sofware and Updates
3.other software.
4.check them all.
5.additional drivers
6.If the system finds any third part driver then click it.
7.apply changes.
8.Done

Comment: Additional Drivers installs Broadcom wireless drivers; unlikely to help his Realtek.